# Class indicating there is an async validation taking place

Tags: angular, forms, validation, asynchronous

**Direct Question**

There is some way I can tell if some async validation is taking place on some control?

**Verbose question**

When working with forms in Angular you can find, that depending on the state of some control, it will have or not some ng-* classes.

For instance, if the control is validating an email address and such address do not match some regex, the class ng-invalid will be added to the control.

Now, you can perform [Async Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation) but while the validation is taking place, there are no errors in the control and because of that, you can't write code like this:

`<button  [class.disabled]="email.errors">`

If you write code like above, the button will be enabled till the Async validator responds with some error. If no error, well that's the happy case, but if some error is found, the behavior is that the button will be enabled for a window of time, that's not what I want!

Comment: You can use shared state for that. When your async validator is working, set the "validating" state to true. Elsewhere, you can subscribe to the shared state, and show/hide, etc, depending on the state. See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. Same technique can apply to async validators.

Comment: @Brandon, Thanks for your comment, but I'm validation using a custom async validator in a template, using a directive. Can I have access to the state of the component inside the directive?

Comment: Absolutely you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is some way I can tell if some async validation is taking place on some control?

Yes, according to [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation), a model with async validation can be in the *pending state*:

> After asynchronous validation begins, the form control enters a pending state. You can inspect the control's pending property and use it to give visual feedback about the ongoing validation.

So you can change the class `.ng-pending` to apply some special style to all the pending elements, or you can access the property `model.pending` to have a total power. For example:

```
<button [class.disabled]="model.pending">
```

Comment: Nice! I've investigated your answer and tested as well in my code, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Thanks to @Brandom I come up with a solution to my use case.

> **At me moment I wrote this, I didn't know such class already exists**
>
> As a side note: I would prefer that if a form control is under validation due to an async validator it exposes an ng class, let's say, **ng-validating**.

## What I did.

I added a property to the parent component called **validating** and a couple of methods, **validationStarted** and **validationEnded**.

```
@Component{/* Some options here */}
export class MyComponent{
    // ...
    validating: bool = false;
    public validationStarted() {validating = true;}
    public validationEnded() {validating = false;}
}
```

In the custom validator (which is implemented as a directive) I added two output properties as well: **startingValidation** and **finishingValidation**. So my custom validatior looks some this like this:

```
@Directive{ /*Some options here*/ }
export class DirectiveName {

    @Output startingValidation: EventEmitter;
    @Output finishingValidation: EventEmitter;

    // Async validator must return a Promise or an Observer
    validate (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors|null> | Observer<ValidationErrors|null>
    {
        self.startingValidation.emit()
        return new Observer(observer => {
            next => {},
            error => {},
            complete => {
                self.finishingValidation.emit();                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the control being validated:

```
<input (startingValidation)="validationStarted()"  (finishingValidation)="validationEnded()">
```

Now I can:

```
<button [class.disabled]="validating">
```

I hope this help to anyone struggling with a similar use case.

### Update

As pointed by @Cristian_Traìna there indeed a class: **ng-pending**. And was requested in 2016: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10336